# Formatting test failures for python unittests

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, string-formatting

I am running a number of unittests to test a binary protocol:

An example failure messages is as follows:

```
AssertionError: Items in the first set but not the second:
b'\x00\x02@=\x00'
Items in the second set but not the first:
b'\x00\x02@N\x00'
```

This is unwieldy as I need to convert the ascii chars into hex manually to check what is happening.

It would be nice, if it was possible to cause unittest to format all `bytes` objects as hex, e.g.

```
AssertionError: Items in the first set but not the second:
b'\x00\x02\x40\x3d\x00'
Items in the second set but not the first:
b'\x00\x02\x40\x4e\x00'
```

Any advice on how to accomplish this with the lease amount of effort?

Note: I have not only this particular comparison between two set, but also comparisons between lists and dicts... Hence my request for a low-effort solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I dug into the code of `unittest` myself.

Internally, it uses `repr(obj)` to format the output of test failures. Short of rewriting all the comparison routines for list, set, dict, etc. there is no easy fix.

The best solution I found is subclassing the `bytes` object and overloading its `__repr__` method like so:

```
class st_frame(bytes):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "b'{}'".format(
            ''.join(['\\x%02x' % c for c in self])
        )
```

Then one can wrap the results with this object within the test cases:

```
ret = func_to_test(data)      # lets assume this returns list of bytes objects
ret = [st_frame(value) for value in ret]
self.assertEqual(ret, target)
```